# Go to first page in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using navigation services in WPF. For navigating to page I use:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new MyPage());
```

For going back I use:

```
this.NavigationService.GoBack();
```

But how do I go back to the first page (Home button) without using

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new FirstScreen());
```

Because I do not wish to create new first page, just go back to it?
And I don't always open new screens in the same order.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way could be to use method [RemoveBackEntry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry.aspx) until there is only a single entry left in the back stack of navigation service. Once there is only a single entry simple do `Navigation.GoBack()`

Comment: You may find it hard to control the lifetime of your pages using this method. Unless all of your Pages are handling 'unloaded', they may not shut down unmanaged and ongoing operations correctly when removed from the journal.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a potential solution, however there may be a 'best practice' method that i'm not currently aware of:

```
while(this.NavigationService.CanGoBack)
{
   this.NavigationService.GoBack();
}
```

[CanGoBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.cangoback.aspx) returns true if there are entries in the back navigation history and as such [GoBack()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.goback.aspx) will be executed until it returns false. In theory this should get you back to the origin, or in other words the first page.

Answer (score 2):

Consider implementing `PageFunction<T>`. This class (derived from `Page`) is designed for scenarios when you want to unwind to a 'start' page. It can return/provide an object of `type T` as a result upon 'completion' of the use case (function).

More detail (better than msdn) can be found here http://paulstovell.com/blog/wpf-navigation