# Close an opened page in WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have opened a new page in my application.

XAML

```
        <MenuItem Header="Admin" IsTabStop="False">
            <MenuItem x:Name="mi_ManageUsers" Header="Manage Users" Click="mi_ManageUsers_Click"/>
        </MenuItem>
```

C#

```
    private void mi_ManageUsers_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ManageUsers newPage = new ManageUsers();
        this.Content = newPage;
    }
```

Now i have a button in my new page

XAML

```
<Page x:Class="Billing.ManageUsers"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
      mc:Ignorable="d" 
      d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
    Title="ManageUsers">

    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="btnClose" Content="Close" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="185,219,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnClose_Click"/>

    </Grid>
</Page>
```

C#

```
    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //OnReturn(new ReturnEventArgs<string>(this.dataItem1TextBox.Text));
        this.NavigationService.GoBack();
    }
```

But the code is not working. I need to close this new page or go back to previos window by clicking the button

Comment: you can check this link .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16809751/go-to-first-page-in-c-sharp-wpf

Comment: change the content back to what it was

Comment: Wehn you set the content of the first page to `ManageUsers`, you have _not_ actually navigated anywhere, so not surprised that `NavigationService.GoBack()` didnt work. When you say code not working, did it throw an exception or failing silently?

Comment: just failed. No errors.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in my comment, when you do `this.Content = newPage;` you are *not* actually navigating to the page, instead you are changing the `Content` of the current page. When I tried your code, I was getting `InvalidOperationException` on the line `this.NavigationService.GoBack();`.

To get it working, change code in your `mi_ManageUsers_Click` method to:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new ManageUsers());
```

I have tested this code and works. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with this but I finally figured out the answer...  To close a page from within the page you opened, use:

```
 NavigationService.Navigate(null);
```

Comment: Wokted for me, thanks!